# R plot.xts error bars

Tags: r, xts, timeserieschart

Trying to put error bars on a time series plot using `plot.xts`

```
> myTS[1:20]
           [,1]
2013-07-01   29
2013-07-03   24
2013-07-03   16
2013-07-03   16
2013-07-03   12
2013-07-03   12
2013-07-03   16
2013-07-03   21
2013-07-03   21
2013-07-03   16
2013-07-05   12
2013-07-05   12
2013-07-05   12
2013-07-05   12
2013-07-08   16
2013-07-08   23
2013-07-08   16
2013-07-08   12
2013-07-09   16
2013-07-09   12
```

I've aggregated this using `myTSquarterly = apply.quarterly(myTS,mean)`

```
> myTSquarterly 
               [,1]
2013-09-30 24.50829
2013-12-31 23.79624
2014-03-31 24.15170
2014-06-30 24.57641
2014-09-30 23.71467
2014-12-31 22.99500
2015-03-31 24.50423
2015-06-30 25.19950
2015-09-30 24.76330
2015-12-31 24.65810
2016-03-31 25.35616
2016-06-30 22.71066
2016-07-27 20.63636
```

I can plot easily using `plot.xts(myTSquarterly)`:

[image]

I can calculate standard deviation easily as well with `apply.quarterly(myTS,sd)`

I would like to add these standard deviation info as error bars to the plot, but I cannot find a method for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use plotting using `xts`, you might want to consider using the development version of xts which is at v0.10 (CRAN version is still lower I think), where plotting capabilities for `plot.xts` have been improved.  .  Then check for simple examples `?plot.xts`.

What you want to do could be done as follows:

```
# Want xts v0.10.0
library(devtools)
install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")


library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GOOG")
myTS <- GOOG[, 4]
myTSquarterly_mean <- apply.quarterly(myTS,mean)
myTSquarterly_sd <- apply.quarterly(myTS, sd)
c <- 2
plot(myTSquarterly_mean)
lines(myTSquarterly_mean - c * myTSquarterly_sd, col = "red")
lines(myTSquarterly_mean + c * myTSquarterly_sd, col = "red", pch = 17)
points(myTSquarterly_mean + c * myTSquarterly_sd, col = "red", pch = 17)
```

[image]

(If you want to keep using the older `xts` library to plot multiple curves on one plot, consider converting the time series to zoo type (`as.zoo`), then plot)

Comment: the same chart can be created easily using quantmod's `chartSeries` and adding Bollinger Bands with a standard dev. of 2.

Comment: True, although the OP was asking about plotting in `xts`, not with `quantmod` plotting capabilities.